# Add only those textbox value whose respective check box is checked

Tags: jquery, checkbox, textbox, addition

```
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1" />  
<input id="reg12" type="text" name="add-1" class="form-control" value="22" readonly ><br>
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox2" /> 
<input id="reg13" type="text" name="add-2" class="form-control" value="22" readonly ><br>
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox3" /> 
<input id="reg14" type="text" name="add-2" class="form-control" value="22" readonly >
```

I have three textboxes and respective checkboxes. I want to add only those text box value whose respective checkbox is checked.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var sum = 0;
    $('#checkbox1').click(function() {
       sum = 0;
       var val1= parseInt($("#add-1").val()); 
       var val2= parseInt($("#add-2").val()); 
       sum=parseInt(val1+val2);
       $('#sum').html(sum);
    });
});
```

Comment: You question is unclear. Also you have only two input in question.

Comment: Never put same ids for two elements, it's a bad bad practice

Comment: I think you want to sum value of input that is relevant to checked checkbox .

Comment: in your html add-1 is name and in your jquery you are using it like id, ($("#add-1").val())

Answer (score 1):

You could loop through the checked check boxes and get the value of the next input and add it to the sum.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  var sum = 0;
  $('input[type=checkbox]').click(function() {
    sum = 0;
    $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').each(function(){
      var val=parseInt($(this).next().val());
      sum+=val;
    });
    $('#sum').val(sum);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1" />
<input id="reg11" type="text" name="add-1" class="form-control" value="22" readonly>
<br>
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox2" />
<input id="reg12" type="text" name="add-2" class="form-control" value="20" readonly>
<br>
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox3" />
<input id="reg13" type="text" name="add-3" class="form-control" value="15" readonly>
<br>
<input id='sum' type='text' readonly />
```